# HTML5 mode in react-router

Tags: node.js, apache, webserver, react-router, html5mode

I've built a nice webserver on a raspberry pi. Im using react-router and apache to run a web application. 
But my probelm is now that the apache server isn't in HTLM5 mode and doesn't display the nice urls as I want. How can I put it in HTML5 mode? 
Can someone find a solution for my problem? I'd be very thankful.